# Is there a Google Maps equivalent to mkmapsnapshotter?

Tags: ios, google-maps, uitableview, ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a `UITableView` which may potentially contain a large number of cells, and in some cells I want a `UIImageView` showing a map of a location, the coordinates of which are known only at runtime.

I want the table view to scroll smoothly and I want the maps in the cells to not be scrollable at all.

I've been directed to avoid Apple Maps. Besides, `MKMapSnapshotter` is iOS 7 and up. I have to support iOS 6.

So is [Google Maps image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/) my best option?

I'm already using the [Google Maps iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) anyway, so I'd like to use it for this if possible. But does it have this feature? An equivalent to `MKMapSnapshotter`? I'm surprised I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: For anyone in 2022, the link to maps static images api docs is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There used to be a `GMSScreenshot` class in the SDK, that could be used to take screenshots. However in v1.2 Google removed this, as you could use `renderInContext` instead. You can see some background info and sample code here:

[Google Maps IOS SDK 1.2 need snapshot of map view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090637/google-maps-ios-sdk-1-2-need-snapshot-of-map-view)

[Issue taking screen capture of GMSMapView on Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590545/issue-taking-screen-capture-of-gmsmapview-on-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases#version_12_-_april_2013

I think though that `renderInContext` (and `GMSScreenshot` before it) is designed for taking a screenshot of a map view that is already on a view, has been displayed for a while, has downloaded map tiles etc. I'm not sure that it would work well if you created a map view in the background, set the camera position to your desired lat/lon, rendered it to an image, and then repeated for the other locations you want.

So, I suspect that the Google Maps image API would work better for what you are doing.

Comment: Your advice was very helpful. Thank you.